# How to provide dynamic 'path' for TLS context settings in Mule 4?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

For the outbound HTTP request, I need to set keystore configurations. The keystore contains the client certificate.
This is working, If I provide the path as ;

```
${app.home}${tls.keystore.relativepath}${client.ssl.keystore}
```

Here;
`tls.keystore.relativepath` and `client.ssl.keystore properties` are defined in the properties file.

eg:
in properties file;

```
tls.keystore.relativepath=/keystore/
client.ssl.keystore=client_certificate.p12
```

But my requirement is,
The HTTP request is a generic one, and this program will route requests to different endpoints. So,the key store files also different at runtime.

eg:
In properties file I'll define;

```
client.ssl.keystore=client_certificate.p12
client2.ssl.keystore=client2_certificate.p12
```

to determine the 'client' or 'client2' word at runtime, I have defined a variable, which examine the request and holding value as 'client' or client2'.

So, to define 'path' value under TLS context/key store configuration, I tried several combinations. But no luck.[1,2,3]

1. ${app.home}${tls.keystore.relativepath}++#[p(vars.'app.name' ++'.'++'ssl.keystore')]
2. keystore/ ++ p(vars.'app.name' ++'.'++'ssl.keystore')
3. %dw 2.0

   output application/java

   ---

   keystore/ ++ p(vars.'app.name' ++'.'++'ssl.keystore')

Anyone can please provide me solution for this dynamic path configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer dynamically to a property using the following sample

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var appName="test-app"
var keystore="client-cert.p12"
var finalProp=appName ++ keystore
---
Mule::p(finalProp)
```

However the part of the HTTP requester  config (TLS) does not consider dynamic values and needs reference to a static property or hard coded values. Thus you would have to resort to multiple HTTP requester components in your flow and use a choice router to route accordingly given the client type.

Comment: oh..other configurations in HTTP requester supports dynamic values(eg: base url, path etc..) Because of this, I need more than one HTTP requests based on number of clients going to use the API..:(